# Starting 2nd for loop based on first

Tags: python, for-loop, nested, nested-loops

I'm trying to write a program that will calculate the future value of a tuition. Tuition today is $10000, with an increase of 5% each year. I am trying to write a program that tells me the cost of tuition in year 10, as well as total tuition for years 10-13 combined.

I am almost certain that I am on the right track with writing 2 for loops, but my program will not run.

```
def tuition():

    tuition_cost=10000
    increase=1.05
    running_total=0

#first loop includes tuition for years 1-10 
#update tuition for year 10
    for year in range (1,11,1):
        tuition_cost=((tuition_cost*(increase**year))

    print(tuition_cost)

    for year in range (10,14,1):
        tuition_cost=(tuition_cost*(increase**year))
        running_total=running_total+tuition_cost

    print(running_total)

tuition()
```

Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: Will not run?  Does it not do anything?  Does it raise some error?

Comment: Parentheses missing on line `tuition_cost=((tuition_cost*(increase**year))`

Comment: It was at first giving a syntax error due to an extra parentheses in my first forloop. After I fixed that, it will run but gives incorrect results of 140,000 something and 275,000 something. The answers should be about $16000 and $70000

Comment: I believe your problem is that you are updating the tuition_cost  all the 10 times... Meaning, in the first pass of the loop, you update the value with the increase of the first year, then you update it and in the second pass you update if for the first two years... If you remove the "**year* part I believe you'll get something sensible.

Comment: The incorrect results are because you are reassigning `tuition_cost`, but calculating as if `tuition_cost` was still 10000.  You can either find `1000*(1.05**year)` or you can do `tuition_cost = tuition_cost*1.05` for each year, but doing both will give you the wrong answer

Comment: I think you are right @Jblasco - does anyone know how I can fix this?

Comment: I would actually go for initial_tuition being one thing, the updated tuition for different years being another one...

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
def tuition():
    tuition_cost=10000
    increase=1.05

    print('the cost for the year 10:', tuition_cost*(increase**10))

    running_total = 0
    for year in range(10):
        running_total += tuition_cost*(increase**year)

    print('the cost for 10 years:', running_total)

    for year in range(10,14,1):
        running_total += tuition_cost*(increase**year)

    print('the cost for 14 years:', running_total)

tuition()
```

Comment: def tuition():

 tuition_cost=10000
 increase=1.05
 running_total=0

#first loop includes tuition for years 1-10 
#update tuition for year 10
 for year in range (1,11,1):
  tuition=(tuition_cost*(increase**year))
 
 print(tuition)


 for year in range (10,14,1):
  tuition=(tuition*(increase**year))
  running_total=running_total+tuition

 print(running_total)
 
tuition()

Answer (score 0):

I think, your program should look like this:

```
tuition_cost = 10000
increase = 1.05
running_total = 0

for year in range(0, 11):
    price_for_year = tuition_cost*(increase**year)
    print(price_for_year)

for year in range(10, 14):
    running_total += price_for_year
    price_for_year = tuition_cost*(increase**year)
    print(running_total)
```